# Trouble trying to sort list of lists/tuples in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of lists containg 2 items, taken from a text file, and I'm trying to sort the outer list by the second item in each inner list (the numbers without num). I've looked at other posts about sorting but I can't manage to get my list to sort, help would be appreciated as I've been trying to find out the issue for hours. The problem is that the sort method is not sorting the varibale data.

Here is my code:

```
def sortItems(data):
    data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(data)


get_file = input(str("Please enter a filename: "))
path = get_file + ".txt"

try:
   file = open(path)
except IOError:
   print('The file could not be opened.')
   exit()

for line in iter(file):
    record = line.strip()
    a_list = []
    a_list.append(record.split())
    sortItems(a_list)
```

The text file I'm reading from:

```
num1 3453
num2 234
num3 35676776
num4 45
num5 23354
```

I'd like the output to look like:

```
[['num3', '35676776']]
[['num5', '23354']]
[['num1', '3453']]
[['num2', '234']]
[['num4', '45']]
```

However my out put is:

```
[['num1', '3453']]
[['num2', '234']]
[['num3', '35676776']]
[['num4', '45']]
[['num5', '23354']]
```

Any help is very appreciated as I'm somewhat new to using Python.

Comment: What problem are you facing? What output or exception are you getting, and what are you expecting? What have you tried? What resources have you used?

Comment: What does your actual output look like?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question to be more clear

Comment: It looks like your 'numbers' eg '35676776' are strings, so you would need `int(x)` somewhere.

Comment: set `a_list = []` outside of for loop

Comment: What is actually happening in your code as posted is that the`sortItems()` function always receives a list of a single element which it is printing. These items are simply the items being read from the file.

Comment: @quamrana I'm intending to read the lines from the file and take each line as a list of 2 items, and all the lines as a list of the lines, if that makes any sense

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM thanks, I changed the index key so it can be compared as an integer, and created the list outside the loop so that it's not overwritten in the loop

Comment: My comment was to tell you what the posted code does, and so you should look at the answer from @PatrickHaugh to see how the code should have been written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `a_list` every iteration of the loop. You want to put everything in the same list, then sort numerically, rather than lexicographically.

```
get_file = input(str("Please enter a filename: "))
path = get_file + ".txt"

try:
    with open(path) as f  
        a_list = [] # define the list outside the loop, so it doesn't get overwritten
        for line in f:
            record = line.strip()
            a_list.append(record.split())
        a_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
except IOError:
    print('The file could not be opened.')
    exit()
```